# Linux Mint: Can I have timeshift take a snapshot automatically before updates are installed?

Tags: linux-mint, scheduling, software-updates, timeshift

Because I'm paranoid, I'd like Timeshift to take a snapshot immediately before updates are automatically installed. Currently I have daily snapshots, and choose to install updates manually, but I'd rather automate if possible.

The Update Manager doesn't appear to have this option, nor does Timeshift, so I was wondering if there was any way I could either script it (I'm a scripting newbie) or if there's some hidden setting I could use to enable such a feature. I didn't see an option to set a time for automatic installation of updates, which would at least allow me to schedule it later than Timeshift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That may depend on which *distribution* you're using (e.g. Debian, RedHat, etc). Maybe add a `tag` to indicate that?

Comment: Yes of course, my bad :facepalm: